# nextjs website keeps showing 403 when directly link to pages or dynamic route

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm useing siteground for my server to upload next.js static html files.
The only link I can directly link to is my website homepage, if I type [website.com/anylink] it will turn to 403, and turn to 500 when reload on any page.

```
module.exports = withImages({
  trailingSlash: true,
});
```

I have tried adding trailingSlash in my next.config.js, but this seems didn't work. Also I use vercel to test my website, and it looks fine on everything.

Can someone help me figure it out? appriciate with it.
website link: https://temp.unmedesign.co/

Comment: In used next.js in netlify there i used _redirects file inside public folder with content as    
 
/*   /index.html   200

check if this works